# What's the best way to output a mongo collection as an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What's the best way to output a collection as an array?

I want to simply fetch a collection and convert the data to a json array. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

(I'm using the node.js mongo-native driver if you want to provide specific code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {})`